# C "gets" command input just skips to end instead of waiting for my input

Tags: c, input, gets

When I try to run the following program, it waits for the name input, but just skips to the end after 2 secs after asking for moduleNumber. I dont get a chance to input anything.

Anyone know why this is happening and what should I put in place to stop this happening?

many thanks.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

char name[30];
int moduleNumber;

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{   //read name & module amount
    printf ("Please enter your name: ");
    gets(name);
    printf ("How many Modules: ");
    gets(moduleNumber);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: That doesn't give errors and/or warnings when you compile it?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that you are running this on a windows machine. The reason it would be skipping is that gets() is only consuming the newline aka \n and leaving the carriage return \m which the next gets() read because it is already in the stdin buffer.

As others have said, do not use gets()
a) it is deprecated
b) these kind of functions are a source of major security bugs and allow hacking of systems. I suggest you read about buffer overflows

Always for user input you should use functions that require the size of the input buffer

There are other problems with your code, for example passing `moduleNumber` not as a pointer which causes a core dump. And the fact that gets() whats a `char*`

Answer (score 1):

When you use `gets()` this is what your compiler should tell you.

> warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.

So, use a more tight warning configuration.

In your case you should use somenthing like this:

```
fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin); //stdin -> standard input
```

to get an integer from console you can simply use:

```
scanf("%d", &moduleNumber);
```

No parsing needed because you get it in the desired type as opposed to `gets()` which gets a `char` stream.